# Getting error: Could not find or load main class after entering correct syntax to run file

Tags: java, cmd, runtime-error, program-entry-point

I am getting an Error `Could not find or load main class...`

I have entered the correct syntax to run this file.

```
package MainPack;
import mypack.Checker;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Start
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    BeginCheck bc=new BeginCheck();
    }
}
class BeginCheck
{   
    BeginCheck()
    {
        Checker checker=new Checker();
        checker.CheckAndDisp();
    }
}
```

The syntax i entered in **Command Prompt** is:

```
javac MainPack\Start.java
java MainPack\MainPack.Start
```

There is no problem with compilation. But i get error on running the program.

How do i resolve this?

Comment: How you are calling ?

Comment: No, you *haven't* entered the right syntax to run it. You need `java MainPack.Start`. I'm sure this is a duplicate...

Comment: I have compiled in that way too, still same error...